# Issue with psutil package deployment in Python 3.6 virtual environment for Apache Airflow ML framework setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to install an Apache Airflow based Machine Learning framework in a Python Virtual Environment in Mac OS. This ML framework is based on Apache Airflow version 1.9. I have configured a Python 3.6 virtual environment for this purpose. However, the ML framework installation and setup are failing due to the following error. Has anyone of you faced similar errors in Apache Airflow setup or Python 3.6 based virtual environments?

```
Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/gokulalex/airflow/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-install-ye9ohe71/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-install-ye9ohe71/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-record-anu_rweq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gokulalex/airflow/bin/../include/site/python3.6/psutil
         cwd: /private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-install-ye9ohe71/psutil/
    Complete output (45 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_osx' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/arch
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/arch/osx
    /usr/local/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=442 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c psutil/_psutil_osx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/_psutil_osx.o
    /usr/local/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=442 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    /usr/local/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=442 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c psutil/arch/osx/process_info.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o
    /usr/local/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/_psutil_osx.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit
    ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
    ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//IOKit.framework/IOKit.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//IOKit.framework/IOKit are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
    ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/llvm@4/4.0.1_1/bin/../lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /usr/local/Cellar/llvm@4/4.0.1_1/bin/../lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a (2 slices)
    ld: in '/usr/local/lib/libunwind.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libunwind.dylib for architecture i386
    clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/local/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gokulalex/airflow/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-install-ye9ohe71/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-install-ye9ohe71/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/79/sh378bcd1n15fyw44lvjnml40000gn/T/pip-record-anu_rweq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gokulalex/airflow/bin/../include/site/python3.6/psutil Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try out `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Is there any other alternative options other than xcode installations.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't gotten this error before, it looks like you might be missing some c headers which are important for this. Also please check your airflow installation to see if you are missing. From going through your debug log this error doesn't seem to be related to Python